# How do you set a timer, that once finished, increments the value of a variable in python 3.x?

Tags: python, python-3.x, timer

I'm trying to set a timer that after n amount of time will increment the value of a variable I've called `speed`. I tried using a function like this:

```py
import threading

def speed():
  threading.Timer(10.0, speed).start()
  tick += 1

speed()
```

Comment: What do you mean by raise a value, 'raise' is usually used for raising Exception

Comment: @MenglongLi From the code `tick += 1` it is perfectly clear that OP means *increment*.

Comment: I've set the variable 'tick' to 200, and I want the program to add 1 every, for example, 10 seconds. So when you start the program, 'tick' is equal to 200, then 10 seconds later tick is equal to 201 etc.

And yes, I mean't increment

Comment: Have you tried `time.sleep()`? https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/time/sleep

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use tick as a global variable as in the following:

```
import threading

tick = 200

def speed():
    threading.Timer(10, speed).start()
    global tick
    tick += 1
    print(tick)
speed()
```

or if you want to start with 200:

```
import threading

tick = 200

def speed():
    global tick
    print(tick)
    threading.Timer(10, speed).start()
    tick += 1
    
speed()
```